# What is the maximum number of bytes the coinbase scriptSig (coinbaseaux) can hold?

Tags: bitcoin-core, coinbase-transaction, input-script

Since the `scriptSig` of the coinbase transaction of a block can contain arbitrary data, what is the maximum number of bytes it can contain? I've seen various mentions of a limit around 100 bytes, but can't find that defined anywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The maximum is 100 bytes and is checked and defined here: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/consensus/tx_verify.cpp#L195

Comment: The check was moved a few years ago, this link to v26 should be stable: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/v26.0/src/consensus/tx_check.cpp#L46-L49

Comment: Fwiw the check has been present since v0.1.0 (see "coinbase script size" in main.h)